# Is it legal to download Purana PDFs from IndianScriptures.com and post them on Hinduism SE?

Tags: discussion, support, sources-and-citations

As part of the answer to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9078/complete-english-translations-of-puranas) question, I should gather all PDFs from [IndianScriptures.com](http://www.indianscriptures.com/) and make a single PDF file out of them and share it on Hinduism SE. The site says after one creates an account they can download the content for free. So I created an account on that site and downloaded individual chapter PDFs. I also downloaded complete Matsya Purana and want to share it on Hinduism SE. This is the only site I found complete versions of Puranas along with Sanskrit verses.

Can we download, merge, host the PDFs (e.g., on Google Drive) and then share the combined Puranas on Hinduism SE? By doing so, are we going to break any copyright laws?

Comment: The important question isn't posting individual chapter PDF's vs. posting whole book PDF's, the important question is whether posting anything at all from indianscriptures.com is OK.  The Digital Library of India and DSpace post documents that are in the public domain.  But it's not clear to me if indianscriptures.com is engaging in copyright infringement of not.  If it's not engaging in copyright infringement, then you are free to do whatever you like with the PDF - combine them, post them as links, etc. if not it might violate the terms and conditions of the Hinduism Stackexchange site.

Comment: I posted a related question here: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/332/36

Comment: i could not even ask this  "query" on there site, due to a bug on their site.

Comment: Well, they provide an email address if you want to contact them: http://www.indianscriptures.com/ReachOutToUs

Answer (score 5):

Note: The following FAQ information is **unclear** (material is public domain and they don't allow copying).

---

From [FAQ](http://www.indianscriptures.com/FAQ) of that website:

> Q: What is indianscriptures.com?
>
> A: : This site strives to produce the best possible transcriptions of **public domain texts** on the subject of Hindu / Vedic religion, scriptures, Indian culture, lifestyle, heritage and the esoteric of India and Hinduism. This site is **open to all** free of cost: it is **accessible to anyone** and does not advocate any particular point of view, person, organization or any religious / non religious school of thoughts from India or abroad.

So, these are public domain texts. **public domain means non-copyrighted**.

> Q: Can I use stuff from this website?
>
> A: Our content is highly researched and authenticated by eminent universities in India. Hence **we don’t allow** our users to **copy anything** from the site partly or fully or with any variation in presentation.

So, they're not allowing to copy anything which means you **should not** publish the text with or without modification.

For further information about 'public domain' visit the following:

- [Wikipedia article on public domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain)
- [Comment on public domain](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#PublicDomain)
- https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/55/296

---

**Conclusion:**

Their current FAQs are **unclear** and **confusing** as they've used paradoxical language:

1. One FAQ says: "public domain texts"
2. Other FAQ says: "we don’t allow our users to copy anything"

Anyway, they don't want anything copied or published with or without modification.

You can [contact them](http://www.indianscriptures.com/contactUs) for further clarification.

Comment: "Some parts of the site are copyrighted. Please don't copy those parts." - which parts?

Comment: @sv. Ask to indianscripturs.com

Comment: "Mention that the original work is published by indianscriptures.com" -- I think we should credit the book authors not the website. But they have removed the author and translator information from all the PDFs.

Comment: @sv. You can check exoticindiaart.com to know respective translators for Puranas. For example,  [Shiva Purana](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/siva-purana-three-volumes-IDI743/) was translated by *Shanti lal nagar*

Comment: @TheDestroyer Ok, but my question or concern is, why does indianscriptures.com remove the first few pages of the author or tr. info.

Comment: @sv. Not sure. But they retained those pages for Garuda and Narasimha puranas.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Hold and wait, see update to answer.

Comment: "The whole site is copyrighted. We have not been allowing anyone to copy anything from the site anymore." -- Yeah, that makes sense because I've never been able to download a full document from their site, but the individual chapter PDFs are still downloadable. The way they designed  their site looks like they don't want people downloading the PDFs even single chapter PDFs.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Hmm... I think FAQ doesn't match their response through mail.

Comment: What to do with already downloaded content? Can you check on that? Can we provide links to existing downloaded content on our site?

Comment: @TheDestroyer and Pandya - Their [FAQs](http://www.indianscriptures.com/FAQ) are now updated. Q: Can I use stuff from this site?
A: The content of the website is copyrighted. **No user is allowed to copy anything partially or fully from the website.** But the 1st FAQ still reads: "public domain texts"

Comment: @sv. Updated/Revised.